# How to match on multiple different error types resulting from joining futures?

Tags: error-handling, rust, future

I am using the library [thiserror](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror) and want to match on multiple different errors.

My `main.rs`:

```
let bus1_fut = bus1::start();
let bus2_fut = bus2::start();
match try_join!(
        bus1_fut,
        bus2_fut
    ) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => match e {
            Bus1Error::Error0 => info!("{}", e),
            Bus1Error::IOError(err) => error!("Failed to execute: {}", err),
            Bus2Error::Error1 => info!("{}", e),
            Bus2Error::IOError(err) => error!("Failed to execute: {}", err),
        }
    }
```

In a separate crate, `business1.rs`:

```
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum Bus1Error {
    #[error("Error.")]
    Error0,
    #[error(transparent)]
    IOError(#[from] std::io::Error),
}
```

Again, in a separate crate, `business2.rs`:

```
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum Bus2Error {
    #[error("Error.")]
    Error1,
    #[error(transparent)]
    IOError(#[from] std::io::Error),
}
```

The functions `bus1::start()` and `bus2::start()` return `Result<(), Bus1Error>` and `Result<(), Bus2Error>`, respectively.

Unfortunately, I get the compile errors:

```
31 |       match try_join!(
33 | |         bus1_fut,
34 | |         bus2_fut
35 | |     ) {
   | |_____^ expected enum `Bus1Error`, found enum `Bus2Error`


    Bus2Error::Error1 => info!("{}", e),
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Bus1Error`, found enum `Bus2Error`
```

`try_join` is from [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/macro.try_join.html).

I am not sure how I can match on these different error types.

EDIT: I tried to implement the suggestions provided by Shepmaster as follows.

In my `main.rs` I have now added:

```
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MainError {
    #[error("Blah.")]
    Bus1Error(Bus1Error),
    #[error("Blah.")]
    Bus2Error(Bus2Error),
}
```

However, I still get the same errors. Do I have to adapt the return values of `bus1::start()` and `bus2::start()` to match now my `MainError`? For me, this would not make sense, because I do not want to have any code from `main.rs` in these two crates.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: You _don't_. Make one type out of the two. You already are using `thiserror`, which is all about creating new error types composed of others.

Comment: Which crate is `try_join!` from?

Comment: @GandhiGandhi [`futures::try_join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/macro.try_join.html). This is why the OP should provide a [MRE].

Comment: @Shepmaster yes- but I think asking a leading question is a good first step and that the previous comments/edits to this post have been dismissive to OP, who is asking for help.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi care to explain what was dismissive? I stated an issue with the post, explained why the OP should care about the issue, pointed to details about what was missing, showed multiple ways that they could improve the question, linked to multiple sources of information about how to improve the question, then directly addressed their problem with a solution to use thiserror, which they are already familiar with. Everything is intended to be factual. I'm especially interested to know how the *edits* have been dismissive.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi Sorry. I edited my post. `try_join!` is from [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/macro.try_join.html).

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm clearly in the wrong here. I interpreted the interaction it as dismissive, because I thought that the effort to list what was *wrong* with the post and fix the question wording puts emphasis on the formatting of the question at the expense of the person that is asking for help. And I've fundamentally missed that **the goal of Stack Overflow community** is to build a technical resource, not manage a friendly Q&A. More importantly, I missed that the advice  "Make one type out of the two" answers the question perfectly clearly.

Comment: Apologies for any offense taken.

Comment: "Make one type out of the two" The error types are located in different crates so I would like to have them separated. Furthermore, in `Bus1Error` and `Bus2Error` more error types will be added in the future. Is it somehow possible to make one master error enum that includes both `Bus1Error` and `Bus2Error`?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes, that's what `thiserror` does. See how you have created `Bus1Error` as an enum that can be one thing or another? Do that another time such that it can be either `Bus1Error` or `Bus2Error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) I was able to resolve this in the following way:

In my `main.rs`:

```
use futures::TryFutureExt;


#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MainError {
    #[error("Blah.")]
    Bus1Err(#[from] Bus1Error),
    #[error("Blah.")]
    Bus2Err(#[from] Bus2Error),
}
```

...

```
let bus1_fut = bus1::start();
let bus2_fut = bus2::start();
match try_join!(
        bus1_fut.map_err(MainError::from),
        bus2_fut.map_err(MainError::from)
    ) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => match e {
            MainError::Bus1Err => info!("{}", e),
            MainError::Bus2Err => info!("{}", e),
        }
    }
```